# Limit of 2 outgoing VPN connections of any one type from Windows 8.1 - how do you increase the limit?

Tags: windows, vpn

I can only make two SSTP VPN connections from my Windows 8.1 machine. If I try to connect to a third server over SSTP I get "Error 633: The model (or other connecting device) is already in use or is not configured properly." (But it works fine if I first disconnect one of the other two.) I can connect to another if it's another type, e.g. PPTP.

Is there a way to increase the limit?