# Windows 7 cannot connect more than two L2TP VPN connections

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I know this something very very few people have ever attempted, but Windows 7 can't seem to handle more than two outgoing L2TP VPN connections.  SSTP does not exhibit the same problem (can't say for the other protocols as I don't have 3 of any of those available to test).  If you attempt to connect an L2TP VPN connection when two other L2TP connection are already active, you immediately get the following error:
[image: Windows 7 L2TP Error]

I can switch around which two I'm connected to, but I can never connect more than two.  If I use SSTP, all three work just fine.

This seems very odd to me.  Why would it matter on the client side which type of connection I'm using.  I can see a limit of one, but a limit of two seems very odd.  If the limit was intentional, I would expect all types of VPNs to be limited and that there would be a much more descriptive error message, or just silent failure.

Is there any way around this limit?  Some registry key that limits it?

Comment: I have found this problem applies to SSTP as well. http://superuser.com/questions/931665/limit-of-2-outgoing-vpn-connections-of-any-one-type-from-windows-8-1-how-do-yo

Comment: I'm not sure why that's happening to you and didn't happen to me.  I actually tested connecting three simultaneously and had no problem.  There may be some other hidden variables at work.

Comment: perhaps you had 1 LT2P and 2 SSTP or vice versa?